# MSKLC : How to tell Windows about the first row of my custom keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

In Windows, one can install a custom keyboard layout, made with MSKLC.

However, when using the `Language and Keyboard Options` dialog, the "moniker" that consists in the sequence of characters found on the first row of the layout, is not displayed for a custom layout.

[image]

How do I tell Windows that my custom keyboard layout is an "AZERTY" variant?

I have used various tools to find out where this information is stored and it does not appear to be in the layout DLL itself. I also search in the registry but could not seem to find what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK this is normal - why does Windows need to know the variant in your case, or what does not work?

For German keyboard layout, QWERTZ is like AZERTY for French. In MSKLC, I first call *Menu > File > Load existing keyboard* and choose the layout "Deutsch" (which is showing QWERTZ in the windows settings screen you shared). After modifying it to my needs, building & executing the setup package (*.msi) and finally adding it to my windows language, my custom keyboard works just fine despite not showing QWERTZ: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTORZ.png

Comment: I would return the argument: why does Windows show AZERTY for the builtin layout and not mine ?